# Help me to prepare for my first job interview presentation

Tags: course-design

My First Job Interview presentation topic for a permanent assistant lecturer position in Mathematics and Data science is below:

''You have been asked by your Head of Department to design an elective module for the final year of the honours undergraduate Mathematics and Data Science programme. You are required to give a five-minute presentation pitching your module to a group of students.''

Could anyone help/suggest to me how or what to prepare for slides. What are the modules I should offer? Below is the whole syllabus for them. Thanks for any help and suggestions.

[image: Year 4]

[image: Year 3]

[image: Year 2]

[image: Year 1]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming a "module" is a course.  But perhaps you could clarify what that means in terms of time extent.

1. You have 5 minutes, so that is 3 slides (max).  Might even just do one!  Yes, realio trulio.
2. I suggest picking something that INCLUDES statistics.  Math and data science basically says stats.
3. My advice is to pick something topical that will interest students.  Something that helps them get jobs or laid or the like.  Internet crap, maybe.  Or pharma stuff (if at a school with strong bio).  Or Covid.  Or global warming.  Or oil (if at UT).  Etc.  If you can find something that interests YOU as well, great.  But try to look for the win/win.  NOT what interests you, but not others.  Something that interests both.
4. Market research or surveying are sort of easy things.
5. Consider some course with a modicum of practical stats teaching (to include survey design, DOE, etc.  NOT theoretical stats crapola.)  And working the kids to do projects.  (which will probably include data gathering*, analysis, modeling**).

*Use Survey Monkey.

**Many schools have student licenses for Stata or the like.  But there's also R.

Bottom line.  Make it sexy. Make it sizzle. BE ENTHUSIASTIC.

Other than that, practice it several times.  And BE ENTHUSIASTIC.  Even phony enthusiasm is catching.  BE OUTGOING.

Comment: Actually, slides for a good talk should have very little on them, and there is a whole style of talk (I'm forgetting the name) that uses about 20 slides in 5 minutes.